# Resolve the promise and return the actual value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have a `factory` that **holds a variable** `user` and simply returns it. **If the value** of `user` is `undefined` I ask the server for the value. I use an **Ajax** which returns a **promise**. But here I want the user or `undefined` if I get nothing from the server.

So basically the problem goes down to couple of lines:

```
function getUser() {
  if (user === undefined) {
    sessionAuthentication.restoreSession().then(function (r) {
      user = r;
    });
  }
  return user;
}
```

The code is basically wrong, because `sessionAuthentication.restoreSession()` returns a promise and I never wait for the result, just return the value.

However, I have no clue how to fix it. Basically I would say

> wait `500ms` for the promised result or just return `undefined`

but I just can not make it work.

Is there something wrong with this solution? Thanks!

Comment: You can't return from an asynchronous function, you have to wait until it's finished, and not with timeouts, but by using the provided callbacks, like `then` in your code.

Comment: Just return that promise.